Список пользователей в телеграм канале через telegram API
Я пытался получить список пользователей в приватном телеграмм канале, используя telegram API, но в ответ на запрос https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/getChatMembers?chat_id=-100********** выдавало {'ok': False, 'error_code': 404, 'description': 'Not Found'}. Вот код:
import config
import requests


params = {"chat_id": "-100**********"}

r = requests.get(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{config.BOT_TOKEN}/getChatMembers", params=params)

print(r.json())

id телеграмм канала верный, бот администратор.

а где вы нашли getChatMembers в API? В API телеграма вижу только метод getChatMember, который необходим, чтобы получить информацию об одном пользователе канала, но не для того, чтобы вам выдало список всех пользователей

Если память не изменяет, можно дернуть список администраторов и конкретного юзера, но не список всех участников. Или использовать клиентское АПИ.
